# QGIS to have infinite map canvas in East-West direction

Tags: qgis

can I setup QGIS in a way to scroll infinitely in east-west direction? 
To achieve this, QGIS would need to repeat the underlying chart (XYZ Tiles or WMS) once the boundary is reached.

Comment: See Mock-up of desired outcome:
https://preview.redd.it/tpz1oan26kz41.png?width=1209&format=png&auto=webp&s=f888b83a099427f1a6abe00a6c01431bb90f8050

Comment: @Trostlooser this looks like it should be an edit to the question.